# Work done by force and tension of a string on a body

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, string

> A person lifts a box using a string passing over a smooth pulley and inclines to the vertical with a 30 degrees angle. The tension force in the string is 120 newton to rise the box 3 meters.

Is there a difference between the work done by the force on the box and the work done by the tension on the box?
[image]

Comment: I have edited your question to fit better with the site. 1) We do not work out homework problems here; your questions should be about the physics concepts you are confused about. 2) You should only ask one question per post. I also suggest editing the picture so it is not sideways.

Comment: it is not homework. I wanted to understand the analysis of such situation because I and my teacher had an argument over it.

Comment: @MohamedHassan The way I read it, this question *is* a question about a concept.

Comment: @garyp Before I edited the post, the OP was also asking someone to do the calculation. You can see an edit history by clicking on the "edited x minutes ago" below the question tags (versions 1 and 2 had the extra question). This is the edit I refer to in my first comment above which is the correct context to read it in.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Thanks.  Now I know to check the edits.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that $F$ is the force on the rope.  The force on the block is the tension force at the point the rope joins the block.  Forces are applied at a point.  It's often helpful to draw a line around the system which defines the system and it's environment.  If the object in question is the block, then no part of the rope should be included; the line would slip in between the end of the rope and the block.  Then look for places where the system touches the environment.  (This works for contact forces.  Non-contact forces have to be considered separately.)

If the rope is massless, then the magnitude of $F$ is the same as the tension force on the block.   If the rope is inextensible (can't stretch) the motion of the block is constrained to the motion of whatever is applying $F$.  So both $F$ and $\Delta x$ is the same.  Same work.

If the rope has mass, then the two forces are not equal. It's very instructive to analyze that case.  Hint:  take the system to be the block and *part* of the rope.  That is, your line defining the system cuts through the rope.  Part of the rope and it's mass is part of the system, and the remainder and it's mass is in the environment (aka *surroundings*).  Then you can set the mass of the rope to zero and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by F and Δx being the same?

Comment: Sorry,  I mean the magnitude of the force applied to the rope is the same as the magnitude of the force of tension on the block, and the magnitude of the displacement of the "left" end of the rope (where the applied force is applied) is the same as the magnitude of the displacement of the block.   So the work done by both forces is the same.

Comment: No problem. So I was thinking about something here: assume that the force pulling the box is perpendicular with the vertical, so the work done by the force on the box is zero, so it must be the tension in the string -with the same magnitude of the force- that did all the work to pull the box, which means  -at least in that case- that the work done by the force DOES NOT equal the work done by the tension on the box, am I wrong?

Comment: You'd have to tell me how the rope gets from the application of the force (left side of rope) to the side of the object..   Another pulley redirecting the rope horizontally?

Comment: I mean θ became 90 degrees, so the left side of the rope is coincident with the force vector, and both -the rope and the force vector- are perpendicular to the vertical.

Comment: Reread my first paragraph.  Now look your second comment, the sentence starting with "So I was thinking ..."  The force that pulls the box is the force due to the rope where it meets the box.   It is vertical regardless of how you hold the rope. The force and displacement are both vertical.   All forces have an object (the thing that experiences the force) and an agent (what causes the force).  The object is the box, the agent is the rope. ...

Comment: Your hand is pulling the rope.  Your hand is in contact with the rope.  The rope is the object, your hand is the agent.  You can pull a rope, but you can't push it or rotate it.  Only pull, so the force and displacement are in the same direction.   You can see why I didn't understand your second comment.  You said  "... assume the force pulling the box is perpendicular with the vertical."    This is not possible.  The force on the box is always vertical.  The applied force $F$ has nothing to do with the box.   Reread my first paragraph yet again.  (Rereading helps your brain sort things out.)